# PlaceholderColor no funciona

Tags: xamarin.forms

Estaba probando un entry en xamarin.forms y tengo el entry de color blanco, entonces quise cambiar el color del placeholder a color negro entonces lo tengo así:

```
<Entry 
            x:Name="txtUser"
            Placeholder="Ingrese su usuario"
            BackgroundColor="White"
            PlaceholderColor="Black"
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            VerticalOptions="Center"
/>
```

Pero no me funciona me sale un error, investigue y creo que es por la version, hay otra forma de cambiar el color del texto del placeholder sin PlaceholderColor ni TextColor (que tampoco me funciona)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

recuerda que Xamarin.Forms accede a los componentes nativos de los sistemas operativos. si quisieras modificar esas propiedades, habria que hacer un Renderer de el Entry para poder acceder a esa propiedad de manera nativa.

> Renderer Android

```
using Android.Views;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using xxxxx.Droid.Renderers;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Xamarin.Forms.Entry),typeof(ExtendedEntryRenderer))]
namespace xxxxx.Droid.Renderers
{

    public class ExtendedEntryRenderer : EntryRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if (Control != null)
            {
                this.Control.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent);
                this.Control.SetHintTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Gray);
                this.Control.SetMinHeight(60);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> Renderer iOS

```
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;
using System.Drawing;
using UIKit;
using xxxxx.iOS.Renderers;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Xamarin.Forms.Entry), typeof(ExtendedEntryRenderer))]
 namespace IGS.iOS.Renderers
{

public class ExtendedEntryRenderer : EntryRenderer
{

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        if (Control != null) 
           return

        Control.......

        }            
    }
}
```